# Gatsby typescript and local plugin

Tags: typescript, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I have a simple gatsby starter, generated with

> npm init gatsby -ts

With also a simple local plugin under plugins directory, generated with

> gatsby new source-plugin https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-plugin

inside the plugin's `gatsby-node.js` there is just a print:

```
exports.sourceNodes = async ({
  actions,
  createContentDigest,
  createNodeId,
}, pluginOptions) => {
  console.log("sourceNodes");
}
```

Which works fine as long as I'm using javascript. If I change the plugin name into `gatsby-node.ts` - it stops. There is no "sourceNodes" print on `gatsby develop`.

If the content of `gatsby-node.ts` is malformed, then I've got the following error:

> Failed to compile Gatsby files (@parcel/transformer-js):
>
> Expected ',', got 'exports'.

the ts example for sourceNodes does not work as well

```
import { GatsbyNode } from 'gatsby'

let myString: string = "LOADED AS TS";

console.log(myString);

export const sourceNodes: GatsbyNode['sourceNodes'] = async ({
  actions,
  createContentDigest,
  createNodeId,
}, pluginOptions) => {
  console.log("sourceNodes - plugin");
}
```

The first print(LOADED AS TS) is called. The second one - not.

I found out an example for gatsby's local plugin in typescript, however it seems to be overcomplicated:

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/creating-source-plugin-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To use TypeScript you need to first install it. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

`npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node`

Then you also need to rewrite your configuration to be valid TypeScript;

```js
import { GatsbyNode } from 'gatsby'

export const sourceNodes: GatsbyNode['sourceNodes'] = async ({
  actions,
  createContentDigest,
  createNodeId,
}, pluginOptions) => {
  console.log("sourceNodes")
}
```

Comment: the typescript was installed as gatsby's project dependency, this snipped works fine if placed in the project's gatsby-node.ts file, but not in the plugin's gatsby-node.ts

Comment: You need to add Typescript to your plugin as well along with a tsconfig.json to specify how to compile the plugin.

Comment: Gatsby's project tsconfig contains include for plugins directory. And from the second example, it is clearly visible, that the file is interpreted as a typescript. But the sourceNode is not called.

Comment: Are you registering/using `sourceNodes` anywhere?

Comment: should I? As far as I know it should be handled by gatsby (the exports.sourceNodes JS example works as expected)

Comment: you should take a look at https://gregperlman.dev/creating-a-gatsby-plugin-with-typescript/ and https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-ts-config/

Comment: Both links seem to be very old, as support for TypeScript as gatsby is supposed to include a typescript plugin out of the box (I'm using the newest version). Unfortunately, it seems that it does not work as expected. I would probably assume, that it is better to write plugins in pure JS.